# Subtract value to multiple rows

Tags: sql, select

Well I am stuck at a point where I need to distribute a value across multiple rows. Since I do not know the specific term, I would put it in the form of example below for better understanding:

Assuming the value of x to be 20, I need to distribute/subtract it to rows in descending order.

TABLE:

```
ID        Value1 
1          6             
2          5
3          4
4          3
5          9
```

Result should look like: (x=20)

```
ID        Value1     Answer
1          6           14    
2          5           9
3          4           5
4          3           2
5          9           0
```

Can anyone just give me an idea how I could go with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perhaps easier to think of this problem in a different way.  You want to calculate the cumulative sum of `value1` and then subtract that value from `@X`.  If the difference is negative, then put in `0`.

If you are using SQL Server 2012, then you have cumulative sum built-in.  You can do this as:

```
select id, value1,
       (case when @X - cumvalue1 < 0 then 0 else @X - cumvalue1 end) as answer
from (select id, value1,
             sum(value1) over (order by id) as cumvalue1
      from table t
     ) t;
```

If you don't have cumulative sum, you can do this with a subquery instead:

```
select id, value1,
       (case when @X - cumvalue1 < 0 then 0 else @X - cumvalue1 end) as answer
from (select id, value1,
             (select sum(value1)
              from table t2
              where t2.id <= t.id
             ) as cumvalue1
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, Many thanks for your reply. Your solution seems to work fine. But, I have a small problem. The table which I have put up as an example above is a result set in my case, but not a table itself. So, I have to do the operation on this result set. The example includes a field name ´ID´ which does not exist in my result set and I do not have a unique primary key for each row in the result set. So do you have any ideas how i could generate primary keys on the fly in SQL? I looked in Google but couldnt find a potential solution for my problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SangameshHs . . . You need some column to determine the ordering of the results.  Result sets are inherently unordered.  Then you can use `row_number()` to assign an `id` (perhaps in a CTE).

Comment: Hey @Gordon Your above solution idea helped me to implement what I wanted but in addition to this I have a small problem. I have a condition that I have to subtract the cumvalue and when the result reaches zero, I should set the value to zero as above and also select all the rows from 1 to nth row where the value becomes zero. How do I select only those rows until where the value reaches zero? I tried using partition but dont seem to be the right one. Any idea for this? Thanks

Comment: @SangameshHs . . . Make the above query a subquery, then select where the value is `0` and enumerate accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Untested for syntax, but the idea should work in SQL Server 2005 and newer.

SQL Server 2012 has SUM OVER clause which makes this even handier.

```
SELECT ID, Value1, CASE WHEN 20-SumA < 0 THEN 0 ELSE 20-SumA END AS Answer
FROM TABLE A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(B.Answer) SumA FROM TABLE B
   WHERE B.ID <= A.ID) CA
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question.  I know what I think you're trying to do.  But your example doesn't make sense.

You say you want to distribute 20 over the 5 rows, yet the sum of the difference between Value1 and Answer is only 3 (8+4+1+-1+-9).

And how do you want to distribute the values?  Using a spread/split based on the value in Value1?

Edit: I made an example which splits 20 over the values you've specified above:

```
DECLARE @x FLOAT = 20.0

DECLARE @values TABLE (
  ID INT,
  VALUE FLOAT,
  NEWVAL FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @values (ID, VALUE) VALUES (1,6), (2,5),(3,4),(4,3),(5,9)

UPDATE f
SET [NEWVAL] = [newValue]
FROM @values f
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        value + ((VALUE / [maxValue]) * @x) [newValue]
    FROM
        @values
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                SUM(value) [maxValue]
            FROM
                @values
        ) m 
) a ON a.ID = f.ID

SELECT * FROM @values
```

Unfortunately I had to change your values to floats for this to work.  If you require them as integers, you'll need to use rounding and then calculate the difference of the sum of new value - @x and then spread the difference over the rows (if > 1 then add to lowest number, if < 1 subtract from largest value).  Your rounding should be usually just 1 or 2.

I don't even know if I this is what you're trying to do yet.