# Calculation using joins and select statements SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I did ask for a part of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394286/subtract-value-to-multiple-rows-sql) just to take a push myself from the point where I was stuck. But, now I experience great problems to find a solution further. Well, I should say I have ended myself to a state where I could write one single complex query  which was purely logic. But, now I in this case I am aware of the logic but couldnt implement through writing. Here is the description of my problem:

Problem :

Table1:

```
REFID      ARTIKEL      SUPPLIERID      ORGID      PIECES      COSTPRICE      DISCOUNT
126663      TV            SONY          922         6            110           2.5
126663      TV            Toshiba       922         4            75            2
126663      TV            SONY          922         10           80            1
126663      TV            LG            922         10           80            1
126663      TV            SONY          922         4           65            1.5
126663      TV            SONY          922         14           95            1.5
```

Table2:

```
REFID      ARTIKEL      SUPPLIERID      ORGID     STOCK_SUM_PIECES     
126663      TV            SONY          922         16            
126663      TV            Toshiba       922         20
```

TABLE3:

```
REFID      ARTIKEL      SUPPLIERID      ORGID      STORE    SALE_SUM_PIECES     DATE   
126663      TV            SONY          922        100          4            01.01.2014
126663      TV            Toshiba       922        100          3            01.01.2014
```

Operation to perform:

Firstly I need to sum up the `STOCK_SUM_PIECES` and `SALES_SUM_PIECES` from `table2` and `table3` respectively.For example: SUM_RESULT is 16+4=20 for SONY from TABLE2 and TABLE3
Next,  distribute the `SUM_RESULT` onto the rows in the `table1` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394286/subtract-value-to-multiple-rows-sql). In the process of distributing, once the value reaches zero, it does mean that only those rows are valid for that "SUM_PIECES" in TABLE2. For example: `SUM_RESULT 20` for SONY is valid only for three rows in `TABLE1` since number of pieces sum up to 20 i.e 6+10+4=20. Now select only these three rows and calculate the average of Cost price and Discount in TABLE1.

This is the most complex part I am not able to solve. I am not asking for one to write a query instead to give me an idea or method to follow to end up with the solution.

I am currently successful in making appropriate joins but cannot perform calculation during join. This is complex to me only because, I cannot use curosrs or for loop and so on since I have to make it performance efficient and also data is huge maybe billion rows. So it has to be done using joins and select statements.
Any suggestions Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Assuming the mysql tag is erroneous. I would suggest trying to make your question self-contained, show what you've tried, what ru want.you get with what you've tried, and what you want.

Comment: Well query which I have written is quite big and the field names are not the same as shown in the example. This is why I tried to create a small example that could define my problem in a simple way

Comment: Example data is fine, but where's your query and your desired output? Put those all in this question and you'll get better response than what you have now, imo.

Comment: @GoatCO Thanks. You are right. I will do my best to make the question more clear for viewers. It might help someone in future as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first part is easy, use UNION ALL and create SUM only over fields you need for fastest run. Second part is a problem. You need a window function.

First part might look like:

```
SELECT SUPPLIERID, SUM(TO_SUM) SUM_PIECES FROM (
  SELECT STOCK_SUM_PIECES AS TO_SUM, SUPPLIERID
    FROM TABLE2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SALE_SUM_PIECES AS TO_SUM, SUPPLIERID
    FROM TABLE3
) GROUP CONDITION ...
```

This will be your table X.

If you want to distribute this sum into table 1, you are depend on sort of table 1. I suppose that your table is sorted as you want and you need split this number into rows in your order.

So, now you need a windows functions. Which get sum for each row from beginning to actual row. Look at this:

```
SELECT ALL_WHAT_YOU_NEED_TO_RETURN
     , SUPPLIERID
     , SUM(PIECES) 
       OVER (ORDER BY YOUR_ORDER 
              ROWS BETWEEN preceding AND current row) AS SUM_FROM_BEGIN
  FROM TABLE1
 ORDER BY YOUR_ORDER_CONDITION
```

This will be your table Y.
OK, now we can put it together and return only this rows from table Y which sum of pieces from beginning to actual row is lower or the same as count of pieces from table X:

```
SELECT ALL_WHAT_YOU_NEED_TO_RETURN
  FROM (SELECT Y.ALL_WHAT_YOU_NEED_TO_RETURN
             , Y.SUPPLIERID
             , SUM(Y.PIECES) 
               OVER (ORDER BY Y.YOUR_ORDER 
                     PARTITION BY Y.SUPPLIERID
                     ROWS BETWEEN PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SUM_FROM_BEGIN
             , X.SUM_PIECES
          FROM TABLE1 Y
             , (SELECT SUPPLIERID, SUM(TO_SUM) SUM_PIECES 
                  FROM (SELECT STOCK_SUM_PIECES AS TO_SUM, SUPPLIERID
                          FROM TABLE2
                         UNION ALL
                        SELECT SALE_SUM_PIECES AS TO_SUM, SUPPLIERID
                          FROM TABLE3
                       )
                 GROUP BY SUPPLIERID
               ) X
         WHERE Y.SUPPLIERID = X.SUPPLIERID
    ) WHERE SUM_FROM_BEGIN <= SUM_PIECES
```

The most important is the last condition and window function.
I don´t know how usable is it in sql server, but in Oracle it works fast enough.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I am trying to implement your solution. I will let you know the results. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Ups, I forget to one important thing and I remembered when I turned off the computer at work :) .. in your window function you must use PARTITION clause .. like this: SUM(COL_X) OVER (PARTITION BY SUPPL ORDER BY XYZ) .. but as I see here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.105).aspx RANGE clause can be supported only after SQL Server 2012 :( .. please check.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Respect!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the first part I would get your `SUM_RESULT` by using a [`UNION`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) of two queries, one on each table.  Group those results by your key for this operation (it's a composite of ARTIKEL and SUPPLIERID, right?).  Then you can join those results to the first table and use the cumulative sum technique from Gordon Linoff's answer, to select the rows where the cumulative sum is less than or equal to your SUM_RESULT and on this result set you can do your averaging.